# Sending multiple emails to the the same email adress

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am currently pulling email address from separate tabs as shown below. I am then sending an email for each tab i.e if an email adress is on both tab1 and tab2 it receives two emails. Is there a way to combine them/reverse it so that each email address receives one email with a list of tabs its on?

Comment: `as shown below` is there anything missing from your question? like codes or images.

Comment: Hey, i did have something but had to remove it as it would not let me post. It was to help clarify the problem.

Comment: Hmm that's weird, can you try to elaborate more about the "tabs" in your question?

Comment: [18-06-05 20:07:56:949] TAB1
[18-06-05 20:07:57:034] [Emailaddress1]
[18-06-05 20:07:57:178] TAB2
[18-06-05 20:07:57:180] [Emailaddress1]
[18-06-05 20:07:57:256] [Emailaddress2]

Comment: Post some javascript and html code for others to understand and answer your question correctly. The problem seems simple.

Comment: I would say for someone who knows how to code it is simple, unfortunately i don't =/.

Comment: What are you trying to post under `as shown below`?

Comment: @Leeballs23 so learn? We all had to learn too :) Posting here doesn't absolve you of the requirement to learn the language. You don't need to include the screenshot, but you do need to include the code you are using, how you have attempted to modify it, and how those attempts worked out (errors, incorrect behavior, etc).